# Seemingly Random Javascript in Page Source

Tags: javascript

I've been viewing the source of several login pages and apps provided by google and when I usually scroll down looking at the different lines of html I come across something like this:

What does it mean? Why is it written in this way?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.bg = new botguard.bg('5gX7J8+0ph/UFe4JyYpuDIAnxI+NBs9ZAE6/BzCpltMBrzYzPfdDPEjHY5zGYj2SOdmp7YnQv10QF6+NTh1AgmF0aNxyp+If1Wf1oaMBn4WdtSk7/cPPFl3LacfpbI3SEY0/EBCbotNKAUaZnUZL6OEgr/bIyyl57diXdXK/9fIy9R3MuO7phTixeg4CA/nEbtyDHDpb+rp8chmyPwpC6Kx4cwiyKGtsevFbPCSaCbpjtf2csDeDluPz7xiBhexWrKPjzVNw+usa7U7LZqTy+E8VT1OAFVEbbeQ4sRBhGVQh+KowZ7X3WYHb2GN0wtfhxdusNx9iisDeGS9jQ/ZuSVVIEFmbEAL3vlFP2GixDucEYHvgxy75kmMJmvdSFrzH1RKenF65DVIcZ6rnf9R4jSsyq78j5wsQRTKJNZxHAdZ1XSR8+JGskM6ma1Ai3iRU5yK6hMKZSAxF5XOCv6jF2jU7QxS1/NueVd9LJANlUtvHSzr5Yg/m8Tsdterg8TWweOuqjAs+rJjuGpfZZO2do42joTZ9VJV+dbasCpcIPwDv4J7q1ZUc7vr7azuOsCb3L0IJZrF2OOnQhyewoCXlv3p0FWrevH/bcutMH+hshmq1IAMsMbdcGDylwzFTfy/+BjULPV47PBK3mZq9IbqlGx3OG+DFOmT0fhoFdFNoPeBQ9/5DklaANzTf5GJ6WKFaSM21A7nLqwQJFfX+jb9v3br4sPJMiAPkqRCZabtdBufIsaxYHUzOTD7KFr978oRBZ7lZUrCdllrRlW7wOZKURcTawNgsSi0zl8fpvXxdv0KCHNSGGYlxUTUTkuLxMT6KDItbzBW4NLeYRGeOS12GKpNNM53aLZ5Mfxfiy50VTBVi6LK65eTEKQFP0vnaFfrRTUNjLr4mXKOfgqUPK4oDYJytrdVzfW2EBs2G5kA0cUcKJoMsrsAHxu/FGPi1EOEKCqzAi51XgtRnj+5Hzj5W95E5+4qagxLnoEcM+tsCNCQ4OAW6Lxc2eGzr4KWHj83mdiFbJJXCeP5VmT2g0PDNXp6OgCs7BLS7NBaBpAQdTehNuShVTqWrjjz1D9Bax761AZckGc0WC4q1cCJVBhAg5VGnmnzeI/sQyT0C9RUE+EkhF+lq75R7+fQubk9Vw0REhlqA8DSgh6eS+9cvRWX9YeFi+FknRwcHI+kFsGDZd/nGSqdUQ2Yb0NKEy6ZfvSzE9BQ76aUphJsDGIHAEcvrLR9fE6NyBEfTOT9J95falhTqAZydOU/7/sbj95IHZ6sqjpDRQPZ+wynUjl0Yf9UDqQlhHtYdpYPC2FFTuEtYfPWNA0oH5jn8P4inHHe2UIvyi/Hh8CNSXF9VmSybustpqZ9tXdxjii0c82AulRFUZ4cbnrjPUZ/Jt44Mp7ka+TMiwvdDr4zgVF0Mg6kXZeAel7VzP1UTiqhh9PtjnnNsVuQW5HSCd1rXAYoybRtacbz3GFuRkZzOPQuBR6zyrUjv6MpE+Al/RDWSaGmveDXxh4ITPIvzU5Ek7F9aBaNVUUzGwMd08UVSEXGplM2aQ9bSgMJ+bBD8efzqvjg3OH69w6l7FHwmXqN4urSveZFYYAsk11n8Hg2NywTI42DVtv6y15FIS/19H5/SSrR3QV36H2VfNv5aABW/u5mwex85Va0UGinZyw1qqhKA8kK/IXObvO4rSC69kZkQBNqe6L3B2sFp3tNLEHAl1XKwk3nIDAKrRuhqQURqgppPkUh6Ty0voWAV/57cH9mRnMemdr9oMir7R4mZ8yuvDBl1hAh4BaZHc3shIifNZ5fORrRRx5OKxOdiCHKJZG1kK9dfe74w05eN2/wmSeXUj5JkItIiZMC5puvJqqiYCsf3bELFzcs/Iiop8VXy3l6zqqjdoDu/HsJdugtYJgbKMU9uYWH1WbJ+ys0urOTqarRTuqqB/VtvVm4TNwHamW2GMCZBCibVhXoG01j3CxU85dPwMfVhvSDi2HrkcKkHh0Q7A8khGevr+XZgMsREo/4TRICeWTuAB5Ahh2fTS3KHChnN02K7RNJ+ZpCa5n7Dcq78lfFaMaRgivSc4ZOTE0slShMVqPmD7MiAjjiUeZXj5rYHjsxYZB2UzBUFQeMwUcoFJ4bbCsioT2WmAoIP83UkMFwyol5TmyG7TVg+yaZGtbFNmeyHvbql3p2oETz4gZVzeZw7uTnbMZPY9qAtocjVXYCRxi5FVo1zx9obcxYrQxYla8beo7yRKHhxeQOYPpFKiUfdQMlb4uPP0xrmKb+CCfp3bnxs0cHrVz5M1HW8T+Ky1I4IB/DlxibkT9XzLGsXJOmA9R/yk+GwQPtqeFAU3g6On5CsSGjg9Uzz0oWbXN6mGOuMQYy83kjzf8rYk622Va/c5cWnkVOZvA89sEg2VaBeiuSPPKWCUlF+urygKzSbvxseZNkfXB91zy0a/VBeg/n3MJyX/0/AmR5WkclnIM01owXyvYf1cOrPIbTxRGmqii6LRXfURy+3gtqtd2qZZia893jord+eQ2ojtFkDjukIq/vjpbntrfGDBJTg9yttMcQ5HhXfB4yaChC0P5zmK6HfCb9BgxUZUgcdG6c0dr+IHQFv5CITR0L4g3q0/qcc44hQJnUDwXKYLsXpb7T0/7DWnPVwNQEnGXNX5ZRNposhbifQ7ht1IC1MdvifYmxipJmjgFGtacEJht0UFo60gmYNxAExSOcOB/XvuFf+e00ty17rQBb2KCo/DgQHU5a4wrGsFTaiVkz+CViI9F+dPYHaVIi/TJ8SeC9zhcSyQSTzrBZQxzoUntSy8G1rQSUgg+RJVIarCHNg5Ei4q+ZkA0Hbo9S0iUBjR+Wtc0duw1RbZcJuXFuMn3AVufrvmILOPJQPUU01fmvs3gK8WNlQVXBL8oqNFx7wL8YbrZCgoUrPnpp0/9bauGDqJiv2KneBqn+bQH6nXsRCGJvKEsjkqvaW6VPXXEHG19z2Fhq6ae1x8UJtj24I7RLd8F49BPDSYkfZIZQzjFRd2fDCN/A8p8eAkvIRNqtqt4ywE/OgA7gQMoDaLmkkLEBM36uV2PPN7o5RXsGQG+igzZIKi9dv2jPfYDU0j7SlEd108dXqRv757RYnMCAjHNEzkCgxs3u0vXI4nOV1f1iFDltthUFPgPjLYoFWhroSHPS14ZRw5/V9ntK2NKzFo9Cw6BdOmVudJ8DXf+d+iK/v4LlzXSMbYvaNoiR0wW9H0BhjV0PMiEyMIx8chc2oOIM2mqAczikpDXeU95ulvRGCkVkOw3FtYlwixjYGmxt6VsvRzzalv5Oyweqe9Q7T/EU/DRZI6mGKkE8DoXj97YhGrxhqoZtCpgZen5coBcOQ2ZPVVNLrEVzcd7MTLrBgjmLsUHOi+1MjYqQHFeOjDuHYOUFe6KCW1a/nOGohvpWn8wBFNWmwDtFx7Ts3cpz7dc1Hmyq7gmHpgHtGxB1D1b0sH5Sp33vt4jomjQEIuw5fdZlYKoIiSSUB+iA5z7px39Hd59/o7nudKWEx7jV9h+reyVhAb5VVnF4+5b74fJgHubmfR1nnJdbZSrk7RK4IuDZ9KtTyNKSWE3UFV6SluTdfxJztIH/b854B5llWMMI+r9bcFm9bW1mO0MYunyXz087+xVs4yKbfCIxWXdqmzjAJWtPbp8+THYkCpM0VuyHbObxyS3winZeIoWEfwPV1JD5dSsNM5YlyA/yyqZyBabYVzJG8rQ6PH5u5XwJFnM/9kuZqn+Eaf5WAkeHQKX5CEJwa/VfEVzgSLuSZK1d7vkrptY9DJWM2aWSjZPjwq0xdQnGtAxDMtFkrm0lz4flYIAcfj6H/zLyBlI+F/Z+Yvsrk5nf0YRwUp2yH7GL/UOoUMJaL0B5bNlDhu0SmLeFcHu4bwUv47Q8OYMTimce+S3XX2VJEe+QKbJas6c83JL14CeB0GDrCxyW7u5czJ7CtWio+R3U7Dd4R/3nIfSO3wrRj3i31Lxghf4g9G0lcICnpw9/U4SbI7Fv7PKg2Ojv3/bc90II4WW9l35fsVEGeC82mPPJprLPJRTh6zacf0c2AD6JxRlZYl8PsMmf+oe2u3XkhfrbLT5yJjTQhXS2woPhqNlAO0at+u4asIkqZgCRchCXgNqK73YdcnLTWGhe/ir6quT2aCXjCq39yBjWkz4mw6oQYvhXosJ8Gqbv5v1i+GG/BvMFLPBQS7cdx6MSnK+bnUJLmOBaQ29p/QvfSAcvdlvYKH2fvR1hnoE8AN9kZcptT93RIaW21GWNL/5dT5OMOlAd75+0+q75Sbijz3laSMTEBxBBgFCbEm9FxbyZbw/4EuIKN76wd24enu8U/W/vhgvc23QtflnQthMI1bGKF4vjB6LcdRG//5Itv2kPggIfBpuKwwuI/kdlEZUeDsrx5gb0I0CGsxyCFmMqYqUKyaEICbC0S85DrrgYTr9VPoQiOTN/iuemEWtSWocePQ2ZVesbFA4aDpwgiatT6NIh3WBXAnEQyvp5nRRHgKl7SCPr6T9ZGOI0UVTGxbX89BjghhC3qAMz4mgZnR8UDpTES9ZXKjqWiA95GQFzbM8n1rzmSgLP0MfqBuc6KVjeSdIsLbLhN5Brl4D11VPonVSmgZDNyEtlXrbEuxFagiraTRxP6RFj6GLYyftOwi1KiSy0zccodzBVCTCr6cH72o+oYZtIEYplwo1mN9kRgpaImsP/QRPHedkeedswJm2t7SaGheqOI85ViB0DuwH+c/H9mL2VJWQGMhvr8oC7Yj0wDu65cfGtZedbZA0aWoXSnkTZQfKGa8nvPJnpieoTBsuhlvA6nS7LouGm2hKfTE0NJFTzaDUr4qd5LaeK7UEM7ZuXimFH7Vww/1Fgl32XKOFk9y3YbYg4EX2MeQ9/yC5taE6P3au4gNLDetUcDQSVEmEwfxL7UN3USZzf5qYq3u6KWB9DTIA+whw/4yE6kH/OLxSHq/crQzQnC2Z7c+sa39KzlG/5JdttTNbB6OySA3TzeLRnWr266soilxGhKc558eOQSZFGcKgS61Qlhl05O4ad+lINHNHdzkV+ApD9luwddhToww7J9EmnD7vZ7p0apKMP8oXWTEoX1hG6DOZEmdb12p7Xm9rnH/C5l0e9c8CH4icj8/VVNzE77uK+aeC3EIR4AzK57IB4c5iot4qxd7HHu3ZIYei0fi5Mio+ZB6lzC0nVJ2IirUqJEJCpfyQ61l9aG7ImTvHcdg1ppf7c5DZ4RKfqh7q7FOOkvtF7NVMAHu2GefGN83g5Mfta9Pi5rv2MaNBOah3q2Zaeq9zxDJF8eFaJgpKLwyqGY6udTLxtZsEtQzPcykskwvpWaTKasfIHIGIrMUgjaFXcEvHLwav4yO9yTj+dENVBZnsttREZZcQE4QIw221IPl5gfOokNVNDbCypdpVLOwCFiztQ00uKDqjciska21EkhQiFZHaQzHsBIzCaIn15Pa4lVUKzWkpIwRSxPNG/oinpbGYJLvKMIIB34Ly3Rv6LFSrrQEhgmJSh3bI10+fJJxW3LpiCC89+FaB+SIb7TFTTJtVyBZmiurJvz08t57nHwp5FZcvdOT10NxX5udF/7Ey/68uPJvrGWKBwvwm5qwQ1sIY1hMnZNO9j6e4r1K5lh5W7ZpjQ6PwdHLxIM3Up3yl8fjaqrkyEZfP1M2ts7H3thLDmw+SOESGcQTfCZUZgxHRCQZHb4I5Mnu8mVYPOyrxWycjETJzBEy8I4GSpMfXrZemZbllyQzACWkNeMVU3YIKMBB6M/bnlTRaS8d8kjjnHttxlsG7oNv0OfGdRAS1XsB3F6VnmsxbBe3qEM1Gf228UiCjILOsFt66cEfv8QXCxIDs2JeSWFxql3BKXMASdF2vEOz9fYr1oeYtKHzVCEjhPR6ucb1ZLmr6nGw7QjI54YYuthltJYBGKNE9imKDB+Ts2wII+EDa+H8Y97xBwRxvBefHt+czOhR4mtFnZrg9rGQuZgWYASSrWQGgvGNLLJ/naolHngRmLYk6O4hUnBsW7ycbA8ncOYgCt/ESNpztt31iN0lYFsctx8cEQEc1UgVMm/t9zgDc2yjdE8c7zzKAjbctOSVqmUI+LCIDqgHwD8wqut5SB6L2u938aXxrd3EeWItdjZZNhqAE9he+tSWEeukFwZXs17asKbmQ9gwK+nXDQel4/+unf2dT8I2gZ/jyNUTO3nnQo5GS4NPCUsjq2BoqpKJ2kTtXnQnn+QeE2sg8DM2mDMDgUiJDs3FChB/pTskzbeIOFHx8yxBnAlk+apF72oRFhkUb+X/bDDSOXH2Z/8xMagxz+THVBNPSisl4TGsVMvy4cLaqueGuxsbhuQk7+MyfH29JYNrxEBeIdcXl+g6J34mUU1iFQYzus6YwVwnovx+JacNTCt+8OUGs8wAel7NWcR3K7PmwHhkYutXHO7N7joLjQJvPUuQnZv90yR5OhYuYbxsBvVVofh2vCMXcsOINQH7XkpJ9JEYSnTg3k47BPjZM+dMVqbRKofjW6xzjCtkkZuueYZD1pHd10qj/hD0eyt7becjACi4lV7twjQcNEIOwvPAv21xjmcTbibfitfEsByh6w5g2C0oFj08FGnqAtuC/t1e/vKgZuq8gantjCLSc/grfFB3NOygdXGLyVUenp/anFbLAS4vNKZIGPs1O3duLyEx0VtynBLKRBaCiRFjK5VCCjMzjkGhvPh/BX0ZVPiY8tpcBrhEx9sbNmi7U/XqKspVebPxB+gpeHzePEQRIN5rXURtHkr6Jw6a4HB6dG9ZsGFTMgClcBJQl09yCcuz002g7iiQmylqH/2X7w4TS9IVuxEZYCOqoV9cJcxBGcAwrqhEdxl4ZJm64MLhRXtYSiuheg6d0e9cBmZ6SjWt6OcWaan4zuToOzidH07Dve+hoJEgs8/aHGyx31uRddrkOj5LqIIz5qQfWyYQp2LKw2/msNXdgtERgC5VX3q2wftNPDinDRcyvGf6VQarhBO9xNIpNDARBfPBVHP7XHE4w24DDuBWNsuDJF5+vop00ByIIVzKZosLAYyHFrhzXNgQX6lm/P9FV8SC/ukh0N0bzngP3pOBitJzFgf7LzVLFCxH5ymsntwVgXYpCRxSmUlLtRRQp2Ab8kZ5gS59lmKNRfQ5HAfQ9MD0uxCSV47+eSC1KFLHoF5McO1YqHxjOH6ecXbfdUOkDP+w3MkbQFA8jmCrfk1mNCnzHTrjEPvmJ6rrgEhh33ZFVA9anldpsybuMywX36eJtFbjuV/VdXmwNZRoHHfjCKWqrkL8PWXbO+hkF84TazjRxxhwoQUcn5q7oj3u4Vh1P3totEvz/7W/PhRYydtdlb1JA7QBs9YqANWDhM1ANBUhKAasr1iR3Sj9G+oQnM6XCHx4M6LXb5u8HdF/ILWOjYENAJ5PnjlxQA/VatkLWds6ZzV5TY9+53PUY1vYhSnI2WF3LSSkMDcvIFhVwaKxXBxS9w+HMeNt7Qjy/tFFcdvn5GQLc/R0gwOqYpZDRplTkscGhxeNJQjJrAqtjxFlweWJ0eJ2Yn3a/p5DD7etYmzGjulB16vEJSNgJtf5mDHqKv5YtfwzeU/Tvf+oE8szGymMz8uAiFvc/xljkM3Y26MUmwpP7Fu97LBBwmrawdyg4Wi3py80ezoy1T8+Hgniv7i93XpX/jNovGln+IfuyhH0hDkSdcLuyOw7hp9ywKjTZPbznHZlpqBAjn1LXhmUSW887sEA2le7Zu6muH7D5e8AWJW7aXtw8zJobB3vUnocSAZ3c//47hhwGa8QAR1mghKbW0Q81rvfszQpILSiMZ5KSFs6Qvgj/NBg1aWGbb9ya7tMq4/iDsSp/SX/+hp3TuaWDXcq065bKJ0Jq4GB4IEXwPrfKo9iAdaEgeR4fuuj66Hjd36+vq5knBFCDPkaXB6OG1LjC2/16Dr8sL6Br7V+7t8/2nDB7l6jeMbwz7phKMdwlUSXNJ20F45RmXnB1sc+ljbeZ5bDr4PVpNx+2gFJKme3NeA2/REt8NaqgGMa2ltg/XKfP6b895lEFVfTthpuTOAQAaFG5lItHqgk7ZyEsr+fhDbUoXMB/ACm2WZsA5bbYXfdA==');
</script>
```

Comment: @Josh Crozier Thank you for editing it so it looks nice.

Comment: It is not "random" javascript, it is base 64 encoded binary that they presumably use using for bot protection. I would also assume they don't want you to know what it means as it obfuscated. You can see the decoded text by running atob(that_super_long_string) and be even more confused. There is a bit of discussion here https://github.com/assaf/zombie/commit/6bdf511898093f9d5c4a649b402e9a2d9f1646c4 as well as a Google employee's response.

Comment: @RobM. Wait if I decode it, wouldn't it then be readable? Could you please explain how it would make it more confusing, thanks.

Comment: It's binary (encrypted text) that is being base 64 encoded, here is a small sample: æû'Ï´¦Ôî Én'ÄÏYN¿0©Ó¯63=÷C<HÇcÆb=9Ù©íÐ¿]¯N@athÜr§âÕgõ¡£µ);ýÃÏ]ËiÇélÒ?¢ÓJFFKèá ¯öÈË)yíØur¿õò2õÌ¸îé8±zùÄnÜ:[úº|r²?
Bè¬xs²(klzñ[<$ ºcµý°7ãóïìV¬£ãÍSpúëíNËf¤òøOOSQmä8±aT!øª0gµ÷YÛØctÂ×áÅÛ¬7bÀÞ/cCönIUHY÷¾QOØh

Comment: @RobM. The compiler knows how to interpret that correctly?

Comment: As a string value, yes. I would venture a guess that this is some sort of sophisticated nonce that they pass along to the server when you login to verify that you submitted their login form only through the mechanisms they provide.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's some sort of security against bot signups. Possibly only allowing clients with JavaScript enabled to use the register / login forms.

Comment: Couldn't bots just have JavaScript enabled?

Comment: Most bots do not have JavaScript engines. I do not know of any off-hand at least.

Comment: Bots absolutely can and do have javascript enabled. A bot is a program that automates some behavior and Greasemonkey/UserScript bots are common place for scraping data from the web.

Comment: Correct, but this system is most likely in place for stopping mass user creation, not someone automating the login process to run on their local machine. I do not disagree that there aren't any, but the majority do not interpret JavaScript.